# For which positive numbers $a$ is the function $\frac{x^a}{1-\exp (-x)}$ continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

For which positive numbers $a$ is the function $\frac{x^a}{1-\exp (-x)}$ continuous for all $x\geq0$?

I'm trying to approach this via differentiation but I don't seem to get anywhere. Any tips?

Comment: Is it over the reals? if yes $a \ge 0$

Comment: I wrote this as an answer first, but it's relatively small and fits as a comment. Therefore, I prefer to write it as a comment for you instead and delete my answer:  Note that $e^{-x}=1$ when $x=0$. Therefore, regardless of what $a$ is, $f(0)=0$ and your denominator becomes $0$ at that point. Therefore, since your function is not defined at $0$, no matter what $a$ you choose, it will never be continuous at $0$ because $f(0$) doesn't exist.

Comment: It seems that this question is trivial whether or not you include $x=0$ in the formulation (because in either case the answer will not depend on $a$). The interesting question (whose answer depends on $a$) is what is the type of discontinuity at $x=0$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\forall a\geq 0$$ the function is a composition of continuous function thus it is continuous ( it’s a theorem)

Comment: I though the same but the answer of my professor is that it is continuos for a>1... so im getting confused

Comment: Maybe you could eliminate just the case a=0 as a matter of burocracy issue but a>0 is certainly good!

Comment: This is wrong. $x=0$ is undefined.

Comment: As I said a>0 is certainly good. For a=0 it's ok if you define x^a=1 for x=0 and the function is continuos.

Comment: @JustANoob This answer is incorrect because the mentioned theorem only works if the denominator is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question it is not right, as pointed out in the comments and in the previous answers. The function is not continuous, but you can choose an $a$ such that the function has a removable discontinuity and "glue" this point with the value of the limit. Consider:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{x^a}{1-e^{-x}}$$
Since $e^x\sim 1+x, \,\dfrac{x^a}{1-e^{-x}}\sim -x^{a-1}$ that is finite and exists when $x\to 0$ if $a>1$.

If you consider $f(x)=$
$\begin{cases}
0  \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad x=0,a>1\\
\dfrac{x^a}{1-e^{-x}} \quad \quad x>0,a>1
\end {cases}$

you have $f(x)$ continuous.